# Portable way to guarantee that the year field of a DateFormat is only two digits

Tags: java, android

Currently, I'm having

```
private ThreadLocal<DateFormat> shortDateFormat = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {
    @Override protected DateFormat initialValue() {
        final DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
        return format;
    }
};
```

Using my Android 4.1, this provides me date in format (In my localization. It may look different for other countries)

**19/07/2013**

However, sometimes I would like to have a much shorter version like **19/07/13**

I do not want to hard code as

**dd/MM/yy**

As the above way would not portable across different countries. Some countries, their month come before date.

Is there any portable way to achieve so?

p/s Not only month/date order. There might be other problem as well. For instance, China is using 19-07-13 or 19-07-2013. There might be more edge cases for other countries, but I don't know.

Comment: @SteveP. Please share your solution with us :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance();
dateFormat.applyPattern(dateFormat.toPattern().replaceAll("y{4}", "yy"));
```

Explanation:
`applyPattern(String pattern)` applies the given pattern string to this date format.

`dateFormat.toPattern()` gets the current pattern
`dateFormat.toPattern().replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` returns the current pattern, with `regex` replaced  by `replacement`.

`"y{4}"` looks through the date format pattern for a series of 4 y's, and 
`"yy"` says that if you see 4 y's, replace them with 2 instead.

Hope that helped. Good luck.

**EDIT:**
As MH pointed out, since this is for android, it is probably more appropriate to use:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = (SimpleDateFormat)     
                 android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
```

This should work fine, since the above method call returns a `DateFormat` of `java.text.DateFormat`, not of `android.text.format.DateFormat`.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng Regardless of the locale, this should work, because despite the ordering, since we're using `applyPattern`, the year will always be represented by `y`,  If instead we had used `applyLocalizedPattern`, it would not work for some locales, since not all countries represent the year with `y`.

Comment: Since we're talking about Android devices, I would still recommend to at least use `android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(Context context)` to get a 'short' `DateFormat` object matching the user's preference.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the functionality `android.text.format.DateFormat` provides, on top of the `java.text.DateFormat`.

In particular, the following method will be of interest:

- [`getDateFormatOrder(Context context)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getDateFormatOrder%28android.content.Context%29)

Javadoc:

> Gets the current date format stored as a char array. **The array will
>   contain 3 elements (DATE, MONTH, and YEAR) in the order specified by
>   the user's format preference.** Note that this order is only appropriate
>   for all-numeric dates; spelled-out (MEDIUM and LONG) dates will
>   generally contain other punctuation, spaces, or words, not just the
>   day, month, and year, and not necessarily in the same order returned
>   here.

In other words, the method allows you to determine what order the day, month and year fields are in, according to the user's preference (which triumphs the user's locale, if you ask me). From there it should easy enough to figure out what 'short' format to use; i.e. `dd/MM/yy` or `MM/dd/yy`.

As pointed out by the documentation, the return value of the method is only useful in the context of all-numeric date representations. That should be fine in your case.

Comment: But that's come another problem, some country like China, they use 19-07-13 or 19-07-2013. There might be more edge cases for other countries, but I don't know.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng I believe that I figured out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want portable, rather than using the date object, you could instead create an array with month,date, and year. (I would just use the cal object and access each of the three individually)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int year =cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int day= cal.get(Calendar.DAY);


dateArray[0] = month;
dateArray[1] = year;
dateArray[2] = day;
```

Comment: The question is about converting date to proper string format. Not extracting out individual information component from date itself.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a map with localized patterns based on country ISO code and a fallback default pattern in case you don't have a specific country defined?